# Is there any Research Database API to get contact email of paper's author from either DOI or paper title?

Tags: journal, researchkit, google-scholar, scopus

I am working on a research publication and collaboration project where I need to display certain research papers details based on a defined criteria. I'm using the Scopus API(pybibliometrics) to get the information. One more requirement that has come up is getting the email of the paper's author. I tried to search for any other alternative since Scopus doesn't give the email information.

I found that Google Scholar through Scholarly library gives the email domain but not the full email address, so that won't be fully useful for me since the user will anyways have to perform a separate search for it.

So if anyone knows of any other option please do let me know.
Thanks a lot in advance.